# How to make wordpress editor honor double <br> (shift+enter) but keep adding regular <p> made with enter key?

Tags: editor, wp-editor

I'd like the editor to behave like this:

```
- Press Enter > produces a paragraph (<p>)
- Press Enter + Uppercase/Shift > produces a line break (<br>)
- Press Enter + Uppercase/Shift twice > produces a double line break (<br><br>)
```

What it currently does on the 3rd use case, is convert the double line breaks to `<p>`. I want `<br><br>`.

How to?